# php similar_text function on two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I have two large arrays of scraped product names and prices similar to the following:

```
$one=array('grape'=>'0.40','apple'=>'1.20','banana'=>'1.80','lemon'=>'10.43');
$two=array('grappe'=>'1.20','kiwi'=>'7.54','banaana'=>'3.20','aubergine'=>'2.32');
```

I am attempting to iterate over the arrays using the similar_text function to return the keys that match eachother closely.  For example i would like to extract the values of `'grappe'=>'1.20'` and `'banaana'=>'3.20'` from the above example.

I am unsure how to reference the arrays and pass them to the similar_text function as this function only accepts string data.  I presume i will need to correctly reference the arrays using a `foreach` loop and use an *if* statement in conjunction with the `similar_text` function to specify the desired percentage of similarity between the two matches.

For example (within the foreach loop):

```
if ($result[] = (similar_text( $one, $two)) > 80) {
    var_dump($result[]);
}
```

Comment: What are the conditions that you consider to be 'similar'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`similar_text( $one, $two)` Returns the number of matching chars in both strings so To get percentage you should run `similar_text($one, $two, $percent);` insted

Example

```
$one = array('grape' => '0.40','apple' => '1.20','banana' => '1.80','lemon' => '10.43');
$two = array('grappe' => '1.20','kiwi' => '7.54','banaana' => '3.20','aubergine' => '2.32');

$result = array();
foreach ( $one as $key => $value ) {
    foreach ( $two as $twoKey => $twoValue ) {
        similar_text($key, $twoKey, $percent);
        if ($percent > 80) {
            $result[$key] = array($value,$twoValue);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array
  'grape' => 
    array
      0 => string '0.40' (length=4)
      1 => string '1.20' (length=4)
  'banana' => 
    array
      0 => string '1.80' (length=4)
      1 => string '3.20' (length=4)
```

Comment: Thanks this answer has really helped me, I appreciate  your time and effort here.